# Listview cannot be displayed after fragment changes

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have NavigationActivitiy with multiple Fragments.

In the first Fragment (MainFragment), there are two inner Fragments (ProductDisplayFragment, PaymentFragment) that communicate with each other. When item is selected in ProductDisplayFragment, the selected product is added into ArrayList where ArrayList of items are displayed in ListView of PaymentFragment.

However, once I switch to another Fragment of NavigationActivity, then switch back to MainFragment, ProductDisplayFragment is still able to add item successfully to the ArrayList in PaymentFragment (checked from logcat), BUT ListView no longer show its view.

Here is my code:

ProductDisplayFragment.java

```
public class ProductDisplayFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String MESSAGE_ERROR_IMPLEMENTATION = "Implementation of sendProduct method required";

    private GridView gridView;
    private ProductGridAdapter productAdapter;
    private OnProductSelectedListener sendProduct;

    public ProductDisplayFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public interface OnProductSelectedListener {
        void onProductSelected(Product product);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_display, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        productAdapter = new ProductGridAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_product_display, getProductList());
        gridView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            sendProduct = (OnProductSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(MESSAGE_ERROR_IMPLEMENTATION);
        }
    }
}
```

PaymentFragment.java

```
public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {

    public PaymentFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            productList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            productList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_PRODUCTLIST);
            updateListView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_PRODUCTLIST, productList);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        paymentAdapter = new PaymentListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_payment, productList);
        listView.setAdapter(paymentAdapter);

        voidButton = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_void);
        saveButton = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        noteButton = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_note);
        discountButton = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_discount);
        payButton = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_pay);
        amountSubtotal = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.amount_subtotal);
        amountDiscount = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.amount_discount);
        amountTotal = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.amount_total);

        setDefaultAmount();
        getFirstProduct();
        buttonsOnClick();

        return rootView;
    }

    /*
     * This method retrieves product from fragment and refresh the listview every time a new product is added into listview
     */
    public void getProduct(Product product) {

        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Received subsequent product" + product.getName());

        updateProductInfo(product);
        updateListView();

        double discount = Double.parseDouble(finalDiscount);
        calculator.setDiscount(discount);
        calculator.addAmount(product, currentMode);

        amountSubtotal.setText(DOLLAR + String.format(PLACEHOLDER, calculator.getSubTotal()));
        amountDiscount.setText(DOLLAR + String.format(PLACEHOLDER, calculator.getDiscountAmount()));
        amountTotal.setText(DOLLAR + String.format(PLACEHOLDER, calculator.getTotal()));
    }

    private void updateProductInfo(Product product) {
        // Only add product if it does not exist in hashset, else increment quantity number
        if(productHash.contains(product.getBarcode())) {
            int productIndex = productList.indexOf(product);
            product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() + 1);
            if(productIndex != -1) {
                productList.set(productIndex, product);
            }
        } else {
            product.setQuantity(1);
            productList.add(0, product);
            productHash.add(product.getBarcode());
        }
    }

    private void getFirstProduct() {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            Product product = (Product) arguments.getSerializable(KEY_PRODUCT);
            getProduct(product);
            if(product != null) {
                Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Received subsequent product" + product.getName());
            }
        }
    }

 private void updateTextView () {
        amountSubtotal.setText(DOLLAR + String.format(PLACEHOLDER, calculator.getSubTotal()));
        amountDiscount.setText(DOLLAR + String.format(PLACEHOLDER, calculator.getDiscountAmount()));
        amountTotal.setText(DOLLAR + String.format(PLACEHOLDER, calculator.getTotal()));
        updateListView();
    }

    private void updateListView() {
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Update listview: " + productList.size());
        paymentAdapter = new PaymentListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_payment, productList);
        paymentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(paymentAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: check your adapter is not null init adapter and attach to list  view add this code inside onViewCreated overrided method this will help you.

Comment: Try setting your adapter in `onResume()`, This will help.

Comment: first initialize your adapter with empty arrayList in onCreateVview if it is null. else set your adapter to your listView.

Comment: Thanks, but none works ;(